# Google analytics api (Analytics.php) doesn't support prettyPrint option

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

When I tried passing prettyPrint into

```
$optParams['prettyPrint'] = true;
$analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id,
                        $start_date,
                        $end_date,$metrics, $optParams);
```

I get the following error:
   `There was an error : - (get) unknown parameter: 'prettyPrint'`

When I looked in the Analtyics.php, that option is not in there.  Is there a way to get around this without modifying Analytics.php?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use prittyPrint with the client lib you don't actually have to handle the Json.  If you think its a bug you could create an issue at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with register. `prettyPrint` is a wrong parameter. Use `prettyprint` instead.